# Virtual subfolders .htaccess ignore language code for source purposes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following rules for language translation.

Both work fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?act=setlang&val=$1  [L,CO=LANG:$1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ $2.php?act=setlang&val=$1 [L,CO=lang:$1:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```

So going to www.mysite.com/en/test.php this works as expected.

However If I change the base URL from `mysite.com to`mysite.com/(2letterlangcodehere)`
 so that all the links automatically have the lang prefix then everything gets messed up (I presume this is due to relative path because is looking to find certain resources under mysite.com/(2letterlangcodehere) which obviously don't exist as I haven't created the folders physically).

How can I have mysite.com/(langcodehere) to just visually appear and also execute the rules above but in essence this folder to just point to mysite.com/ for  a script,css,source perspective is this possible with .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting this rule before your existing rules:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

If this doesn't work then you have 2 options:

1. use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thanks , It partly worked but this is the correct solution , I guess I have to stick with the absolute urls.. because the lang path might or might not exist so relative cannot be an option.

Comment: Yes that's true, absolute URLs are best for virtual folders / pretty URLs.